# How do I split strings from a list and store them to another list?

Tags: python

I am trying to split the strings from a list based on the whitespaces.

My code:

```
line=['abc def','ghi jk']
for x in line:
    word=x.split(' ')
print(word)
```

Expected output:

```
['abc','def','ghi','jk']
```

But I keep getting the output as:

```
['ghi','jk']
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time `word=x.split(' ')` runs, the previous value of `words` is replaced by a new value. In your case, the first iteration of the loop creates `word = ['abc','def']`, and the second iteration replaces it by `word = ['ghi','jk']`.

You need to store the result of each iteration into a new list:

```
line = ['abc def', 'ghi jk']
result = []
for x in line:
     result.extend(x.split(' '))
print(result)
```

Comment: What's the difference between `extend` and `append`? As far as I know, both of these add elements to a `list`.

Comment: @FMA `list1.extend(list2)` adds to list1 all the elements in list2. `append` just adds an element to a list, so `[1, 2, 3].append([4, 5])` equals `[1, 2, 3, [4, 5]]` which is not what you want here

Answer (score 1):

You can join the strings with a space first before splitting the string by spaces:

```
' '.join(line).split()
```

This returns:

```
['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jk']
```

Answer (score 0):

A neat one-liner:

Given `line = ['abc def', 'ghi jk']`

```
word = [item for sublist in [elem.split() for elem in line] for item in sublist]
```

Then you have

```
>>> word
['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jk']
```

What happens here? The `[elem.split() for elem in line]` is a [list-comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), taking `elem.split()` for each element in the original list `line`, and putting each result in a list.

```
>>> [elem.split() for elem in line]
[['abc', 'def'], ['ghi', 'jk']]
```

Suppose then, that we again use list-comprehension and take from each element of our new nested list, each element it has, and puts it in a list. The procedure is called flattening of a list, and is of the form:

```
flattened_list = [item for sublist in nestedlists for item in sublist]
```

Answer (score 0):

Split it, then flatten

```
line = ['abc def','ghi jk']
temp = [s.split(' ') for s in line]
res = [c for s in temp for c in s]
print(res)
```

Result

```
['abc','def','ghi','jk']
```

---

Or by using  **operator** and **reduce**

```
import operator
from functools import reduce
line = [s.split(' ') for s in line]
res = reduce(operator.concat, line)
print(res)
```

Result:

```
['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jk']
```